# Conditions over old batches of graduates for fresher openings

Tags: recruitment, hiring-process, human-resources, hiring

I applied in a company for the job role of Associate Software Engineer fresher on 20th September with an employee referral. Even though the job requirement matched my resume it wasn't shortlisted. It was shown in the company website that in case you do not get a response within 10 days, it would mean that your profile does not fit our current requirements. I didn't get any response from the company yet. Two hours ago they posted for the same job role in LinkedIn.

**The recruitment was for 2021-2023 batches. For 2022 batch or older batch, do HRs usually prefer candidates who have done internship or any relevant course and reject those who don't have any work experience? Is there any common practice regarding the same? In the requirements section of the job which I applied it was said that any internship/certificate/project will be considered an advantage?**

Comment: ",Do HRs usually prefer candidates who have done internship or any relevant course and reject those who don't have any work experience" why does it matter? Are you going to suddenly have any of those if we say "yes"?

Comment: I am confused... When they reposted the requirements were they the same or different to the requirements as stated when you applied the first time?

Comment: Something similar happened to me on an application for my first job out of school. I sent a nice email along the lines of "I see that you have re-advertised the junior SW engineer position that I applied for on xx/yy/zz. I assume this is because I was not a good fit for the position ? Thanks anyway..." - called for an interiew the next day, offered the job the day after. Worked there for 2 years.

Comment: Whats a "fresher"?

Comment: @solarflare - 'fresher' is a regional (India primarily?) term for a recent ("fresh") university graduate.

Answer (score 4):

Under normal circumstances you have been given your answer.

> in case you do not get a response within 10 days, it would mean that your profile does not fit our current requirements.

It doesn't matter what you think their requirements should be or whether you think you fulfil them - if it's been ten days, assume that they don't want you for some reason. The fact that they have reposted the position is irrelevant. They have looked at your resume and they don't want to interview you. They are still looking for somebody, but that somebody is not you. Don't waste time trying to work out what the reason is. Do have a look at your resume and make sure you have indicated all your relevant experience, qualifications and skill on it.

However **in your situation you have one last card you can play**. Since you are an employee referee, reach out to the employee who gave you the reference and ask if they can ask the company to give some feedback. Companies are often more willing to give feedback to a referee than to a random applicant.

Comment: Nice bonus suggestion to check with the one who gave the reference

Answer (score 1):

> Do HRs usually prefer candidates who have done internship or any relevant course and reject those who don't have any work experience?

It's reasonable to assume that a candidate with previous experience is better than one without.

> In the requirements section of the job which I applied it was said that any internship/certificate/ project will be considered an advantage

This will give us further information that *yes* having any internship or certificate is and advantage to *them*.

Perhaps for other companies this is not so relevant, or for some completely irrelevant, but this current company explicitly states (according to what you posted) that they consider previous experience as an advantage.